# How to flush the whole instruction cache on powerpc?

Tags: caching, flush, powerpc

I want to flush the **whole instruction cache** on a powerpc 750 (Ubuntu on Apple imac G5).
 I tried to use this function defined in cacheflush.h:

```
flush_icache_range(unsigned long start, unsigned long stop)
```

For some values of 'start' and 'stop' arguments, the machine just hangs. If anybody knows the correct usage of this function or any other alternate way to flush icache, it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was flushing instruction cache on `effective addresses`, whereas the correct way is to flush `virtual address`.